# retrieve several values previous to several given dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got a `values` table such as:

```
id | user_id | value | date
---------------------------------
1  |      12 |    38 | 2014-04-05
2  |      15 |    19 | 2014-04-05
3  |      12 |    47 | 2014-04-08
```

I want to retrieve all values for given dates. However, if I don't have a value for one specific date, I want to get the previous available value. For instance, with the above dataset, if I query values for user 12 for dates `2014-04-07` and `2014-04-08`, I need to retrieve 38 and 47.

I succeeded using two queries like:

```
SELECT *
FROM values
WHERE date <= $date
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

However, it would require `dates.length` requests each time. So, I'm wondering if there is any more performant solution to retrieve all my values in a single request?

Comment: What do you mean by `dates.length` requests?

Comment: If I got two dates, then I would need 2 requests like above. If I got 10, then it would require 10 requests. I will essentially get between 5 and 10 dates each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you would use a [`VALUES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-values.html) clause to specify multiple values in a single query.

If you have only occasional dates missing (and thus no big gaps in dates between rows for any particular `user_id`) then this would be an elegant solution:

```
SELECT dt, coalesce(value, lag(value) OVER (ORDER BY dt)) AS value
FROM (VALUES ('2014-04-07'::date), ('2014-04-08')) AS dates(dt)
LEFT JOIN "values" ON "date" = dt AND user_id = 12;
```

The `lag()` [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) picks the previous `value` if the current row does not have a `value`.

If, on the other hand, there may be big gaps, you need to do some more work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dt, first_value(value) OVER (ORDER BY diff) AS value
FROM (
  SELECT dt, value, dt - "date" AS diff
  FROM (VALUES ('2014-04-07'::date), ('2014-04-08')) AS dates(dt)
  CROSS JOIN "values"
  WHERE user_id = 12) sub;
```

In this case a `CROSS JOIN` is made for `user_id = 12` and differences between the dates in the `VALUES` clause and the table rows computed, in a sub-query. So every row has a value for field `value`. In the main query the `value` with the smallest difference is selected using the `first_value()` window function. Note that ordering on `diff` and picking the first row would not work here because you want values for multiple dates returned.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly. I was sure that there were a specific feature in PSQL, and indeed: I discovered the world of Window functions. :)